# remove tags from query input before submit trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Would like to remove highlighted text tags   from the input query 'q' before 'submit' is triggered.

> **$("#q").val()** in the code below has tags `<b> </b>` around some terms within that text. I tried using .`text()` for `$("\#q")` before submit trigger with no change in result.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("\#q").autocomplete('#{url_for_home}/autocomplete', {  ## backslash escaped #q as that is a macro defined in VM_global_library.vm
           extraParams:{
             'suggest.q': function() { return $("\#q").val();},
             'wt': 'velocity',
             'v.template': 'suggest'
           }
         }
      ).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode === 13){
          $("#query-form").trigger('submit');
        }
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the onsubmit property to call your editing function.

```
$("\#q").onsubmit = function() {
         // code here
       }
```

You can put it almost anywhere in the function you've already created, for example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("\#q").autocomplete('#{url_for_home}/autocomplete', {  ## backslash escaped #q as that is a macro defined in VM_global_library.vm
       extraParams:{
         'suggest.q': function() { return $("\#q").val();},
         'wt': 'velocity',
         'v.template': 'suggest'
       }
     }
  ).onsubmit(function() {
     // code here
   }).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13){
      $("#query-form").trigger('submit');
    }
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: thanks. I am a beginner in JS. could you tell me where I place this within the script tag?

Comment: There are several places you can put it, I'll edit my answer to give an example.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it doesn't work in removing tags- .onsubmit(function() {
        $("#q").val() == $("#q).val().text();

Comment: @sunskin Don't use the == use just = if you're trying to assign a value

Comment: @sunskin Hmm maybe something else is wrong.  I know you can't use .text() of input elements, and you said only some of the terms inside have the html tags around them.  Maybe it has something to do with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110561/discussion-between-cameron637-and-sunskin).